# Ruby return in yield block called from a method with ensure

Tags: ruby

```
def foo
  puts "in foo"
  s = yield
  puts "s = #{s}"
  return 2
ensure
  puts "in ensure"
  return 1
end

def bar
  foo do
    puts "in bar block"
    return 3
  end
  return 4
end


[36] pry(main)> r = bar
in foo
in bar block
in ensure
=> 4
```

I'd expect r = 3 but it turns out it is r = 4.  If I remove the ensure code, r = 3 is expected.  Why is it?

```
def foo
  puts "in foo"
  s = yield
  puts "s = #{s}"
  return 2
end

r = bar
in foo
in bar block
=> 3
```

Comment: This [blog](http://railsware.com/blog/2012/11/20/yield-gotcha-in-ruby-blocks/) is attempted to explain you .. what's going on..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a Ruby's feature of "unwinding the stack" from blocks. How your return works step by step:

1. You return 3 from `bar` block. `return_value` = 3 and Ruby marks that it is a return value from block, so it should unwind the stack and return 3 from parent function. It would not return to `foo` at all if there was no `ensure` section. It is very important difference between returning from functions and from blocks.
2. But Ruby always executes `ensure`, and there is one more `return` in `ensure` section of `foo`.
3. After `return 1` in `ensure` section of `foo`, `return_value` is 1. It is not a value from block, so Ruby "forgets" about previous `return 3` and forgets to return it from `bar`.
4. It returns 1 from `foo` and `4` from `bar`.

Moreover, if you write `next 3` instead of `return 3` in the block - it will return to `foo` after `yield` and execute `puts "s = #{s}"; return 2` even without the ensure block. This is a magical Ruby feature for iterators and enumerators.